# how to insert an image into a div with jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have the following markup:
`<div class="user-photo">
     <img src="" />
 </div>`

I want to insert an image in that div when I click another image on a page. My code looks like this:

    `$('body').on('click', '.image', function() {
        $('.user-photo').children('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    });`

But it is not working

Comment: How is it not working? Do you see an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WnC9B/8/

```
$('body').on('click', '.image', function(e) {
  $('.user-photo').children('img').attr('src', $(e.target).attr('src'));
 });​
```

Comment: i can not toggle between clicking multiple images

Comment: when i click on the image it inserts it , but when i click on another image it doesn't insert that image, so i can not click multiple images and make the div image change

Comment: i am trying to build a photo gallery btw

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `this` in the wrong way (this refers to the bodyin this example, you should use `e.target` to refer to the clicked element)

```
$('body').on('click', '.image', function(e) { 
  $('.user-photo > img').attr('src', $(e.target).attr('src')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .tmpl() of jquery. It will be used to append html content in div in your case.

```
$.tmpl("<div class="user-photo"> <img src='' /> </div>")..appendTo("#targetdiv");
```

Another way is:

```
$('#div').html('<div class="user-photo"> <img src='' /> </div>')
```